# Why does 'dd' produce different files for same USB stick?

Tags: linux, usb, mount, dd

I've just saved the restore for *Windows 8.1* onto a USB stick; now, I've been creating the *low level* copy of it on my HDD, by executing the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdf of=/disk2/Archive/windows8.1-restore.img bs=4M oflag=direct
```

I wanted to double check that my 'dd' command was ok, so I've rerun it two times, specifying both `bs=8M` and `bs=16M`; I've checked the size and it's exactly the same, but *md5sum* gives a different output for the three files:

```
c38a2b07b3d473d3f1876331edc2647b  windows8.1-restore.img.4M
568e382844431eef63d4ba6dc4c2c5ac  windows8.1-restore.img.8M
568e382844431eef63d4ba6dc4c2c5ac  windows8.1-restore.img.16M
```

I believe I have *unmounted* the USB stick the second and third time.

Should I be worried about anything?

**edit**

Total file size is `31024349184` bytes in  all cases, my understanding of `bs=xxx` is to just control the speed in case one wants to *dump* the whole USB sitck/drive.

Comment: Was the stick unmounted when you ran `dd` with `bs=4M`?

Comment: Nope. I guess I should have, right?

Comment: Right, you should have it be unmounted.  (Or, maybe mounted read-only.)  I'm also not sure where you're getting your block sizes from.  I would use bs=512.  I pretty much always use bs=512 except when using a CD drive because they may want a different block size (like bs=2048 , or perhaps bs=2352 or whatever block size is being used, as noted by <A HREF="http://www.osta.org/technology/cdqa7.htm">CD block sizes</A>).

Comment: @TOOGAM Here's [how to create links](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @TOOGAM Isn't `bs=xxx` just determining the speed only? At the end of the day it shouldn't make any difference, right? I expect that if the last block is less than `xxx`, to be truncated _automagically_. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Emanuele I don't think you are wrong. Small block sizes with `dd` are known to kill performance because it forces many more read and write calls than would otherwise be necessary. I believe gronostaj is correct, your problem is that you dd'd the disk with the file system mounted. *Assuming you haven't remounted the file system since,* you should be able to verify this by re-running your initial dd command; you should see an identical MD5sum from that invocation as well.

Comment: 1). http://www.osta.org/technology/cdqa7.htm = above link, corrected.

Comment: 2)  I have just encountered an issue where where bs=4k/16k/64k/200k resulted in files with different checksums but the same size.  (these were copies of a .dmg file that IIRC, was not open, and I bet is read only; will check.).  I'm looking through SE before posting a question; I'm baffled...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing small amounts of data to a drive is slow, so system buffers writes to commit them all at once later. When the buffer contains enough data for an efficient write operation or when some process uses [`sync` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync), the buffer is flushed to device.

`dd` performs a low-level copy, ie. it reads data that is physically present on a device. It doesn't take buffers into account.

If the drive was mounted when you ran `dd bs=4M`, then it's possible that some writes were already buffered, but not commited. You have dumped the drive without buffered changes.

`umount` calls `sync` internally to ensure data integrity. Unmounted devices usually aren't accessed unless you explicitly ask some process to do it, so the drive was unlikely to change after unmounting.

Then you ran `dd` twice on the drive without mounting it in-between. That's why `bs=8M` and `bs=16M` calls produced same results.

Drive was modified between `bs=4M` and `bs=8M` calls, though, so the first dump is different. `bs=` didn't matter, calling `umount` did.

You should always unmount device before using `dd` on it, otherwise some other process may modify its contents while `dd` is doing its job and break file integrity.

Comment: I thought I'd been a bit of an idiot in having it _mounted_ the first time around when I executed `dd`. I guess I'll keep the file taken with the device _unmounted_. Scary!